# Regex: Match any punctuation character except . and _

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there an easy way to match all punctuation except period and underscore, in a C# regex? Hoping to do it without enumerating every single punctuation mark.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Use Regex Subtraction

```
[\p{P}-[._]]
```

See the [.NET Regex documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994330.aspx). I'm not sure if other flavors support it.

#### C# example

```
string pattern = @"[\p{P}\p{S}-[._]]"; // added \p{S} to get ^,~ and ` (among others)
string test = @"_""'a:;%^&*~`bc!@#.,?";
MatchCollection mx = Regex.Matches(test, pattern);
foreach (Match m in mx)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", m.Value, m.Index, m.Length);
}
```

#### Explanation

The  pattern is a Character Class Subtraction.  It starts with a standard character class like `[\p{P}]` and then adds a Subtraction Character Class like `-[._]`, which says to remove the `.` and `_`.  The subtraction is placed inside the `[ ]` after the standard class guts.

Comment: That didn't seem to match ^, ~ or `; could I be testing it wrong, or does .NET not consider them to be punctuation?

Comment: If you drop the -[._], then \p{P} doesn't match them either.

Comment: So .NET doesn't consider them to be punctuation?

Comment: I am surprised that the grave accent is not considered punctuation.  I suppose you need to define what you mean by punctuation.  You can add the "symbol" character class (\p{S}) to pickup the accent, carat and tilde.  I will edit my example.

Answer (score 19):

The answers so far do not respect ALL punctuation. This should work:

```
(?![\._])\p{P}
```

(Explanation: Negative lookahead to ensure that neither `.` nor `_` are matched, then match any unicode punctuation character.)

Comment: That didn't seem to match ^, ~ or `; could I be testing it wrong, or does .NET not consider them to be punctuation?

Comment: @Smashery These are accents, you would never use those as punctuation in the English language.

Comment: Thanks very much! I decided to accept Les's answer, because I find Regex Subtraction easier to understand conceptually; thus I'm more likely to remember it; but +1 - thanks for teaching me some new things! (Wish I could accept two answers)

Comment: @Smashery - Even though the character class subtraction is easier to understand, be prepared to see this very common construct in Regex.  The negative look ahead is used a lot.  And it may be supported by more regex versions than Subtraction (my guess).

Answer (score 9):

Here is something a little simpler.  Not words or white-space (where words include A-Za-z0-9 AND underscore).

```
[^\w\s.]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use a negated character class like this:

```
[^0-9A-Za-z._\s]
```

This includes every character *except* those listed. You may need to exclude more characters (such as control characters), depending on your ultimate requirements.

Comment: Okay, add space to the exclusion list.

Comment: Would work on a limited set, but a lot of printable characters (currency symbols, mathematical symbols, diacritics etc.) are going to match this.

Comment: How about `º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ` etc. (you get the idea)?

Comment: Can anyone explain why the full stop does not need escaping in this? Why isn't the full stop excluding every character? It doesn't - this works as described - I just don't understand the logic. This also seems to work as described if you do escape the full stop. IE, `Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\.]").Replace("a_b:c-d.e 4\\5&6%c£7.","_")` returns `"a_b_c_d.e_4_5_6_c_7."`, as does `Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9.]")` Better still does anyone have a decent RTFM link?

Comment: @Chris: The full stop does not need escaping there because full stop has no special meaning when inside `[]` brackets. For convenience, most regex parsers will allow you to escape it there anyway with no change in meaning.