# How to remove punctuation from a string with exceptions using regex in bash

Tags: bash, punctuation, character-class

Using the command `echo "Jiro. Inagaki' & Soul, Media_Breeze." | tr -d '[:punct:]'` prints the string "Jiro Inagaki  Soul MediaBreeze".

However, I want to find a regular expression that will remove all punctuation except the underscore and ampersand i.e. I want "Jiro Inagaki & Soul Media_Breeze".

Following advice on character class subtraction from the sources listed at the bottom, I've tried replacing `[:punct:]` with the following:

- `[\p{P}\-[&_]]`
- `[[:punct:]-[&_]]`
- `(?![\&_])\p{P}`
- `(?![\&_])[:punct:]`
- `[[:punct:]-[&_]]`
- `[[:punct:]&&[&_]]`
- `[[:punct:]&&[^&_]]`

... but I haven't gotten anything to work so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Sources:

- [Regex: Match any punctuation character except . and _](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973602/regex-match-any-punctuation-character-except-and)
- https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: [`tr` does not use regular-expressions](https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html). It’s syntax superficially resembles the popular PCRE dialect, but it isn’t a regex evaluator. Consider using `sed` and `awk` instead of `tr`.

Comment: I don't think this is regex, it sounds like OP just wants to remove punctuation; `tr` should be fine for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the punctuation marks you want removed, e.g.

```
>echo "Jiro. Inagaki' & Soul, Media_Breeze." | tr -d "[.,/\\-\=\+\{\[\]\}\!\@\#\$\%\^\*\'\\\(\)]"
Jiro Inagaki & Soul Media_Breeze
```

Or, alternatively,

```
>echo "Jiro. Inagaki' & Soul, Media_Breeze." | tr -dc '[:alnum:] &_'
Jiro Inagaki & Soul Media_Breeze
```

Comment: The second solution worked perfect, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I thought this would be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find anything similar on SO. Glad it solved your issue.

Comment: I think the solution is a bit wrong. It should be `tr -dc '[:alnum:] &_'`. The `[]` in `tr` is only for character classes and is otherwise already a character set, so it doesn't have bracket expressions. The brackets will cause `tr` to not delete brackets. `echo '[hi &_123]' | tr -dc '[:alnum:][ &_]' # [hi &_123]`. `echo '[hi &_123]' | tr -dc '[:alnum:] &_' # hi &_123`. The un-complemented solution should also be adjusted. I don't think it needs so many backslash escapes.

Comment: The un-complemented solution can have less or no escapes if you use single quotes. You also don't need to escape brackets if they aren't in the character class form `[:class:]`.

Comment: You're absolutely right @dosentmatter, thank you for the correction. Regarding the backslash escapes, I wasn't able to find a working solution apart from the one posted; I would be very interested to see your alternative with single quotes

Comment: No problem. I'd implement it like this with single quotes ``echo -n 'abcd_!"#$%()*+,-./:;<=>?@][\\^`{}|~'"'" | tr -d '!"#$%()*+,-./:;<=>?@][\\^`{}|~'"'"``. The only characters that need special handling are backslash (escaped with ``\\``) and single quote (concatenated at end with separate double quote string`"'"`. I didn't follow your list of punctuation exactly. I based mine off of [the list in GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#index-punct-character-class), using similar order. I included all punctuation except `_`.

Comment: If possible, can you please post that as an answer to the question @dosentmatter? It's clearly 'more correct' than my answer and I really appreciate you taking the time to explain it further

Answer (score 2):

Posting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797290/how-to-remove-punctuation-from-a-string-with-exceptions-using-regex-in-bash/67797319?noredirect=1#comment128723773_67797319) as an answer as requested by [@jared_mamrot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797290/how-to-remove-punctuation-from-a-string-with-exceptions-using-regex-in-bash/67797319?noredirect=1#comment128727883_67797319).

You can manually type out the set of punctuation, excluding `_`, that you want to delete. I took my punctuation set from [GNU docs on `[:punct:]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#index-punct-character-class):

> ‘[:punct:]’ Punctuation characters; in the ‘C’ locale and ASCII
> character encoding, this is ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ?
> @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.

You can also look at [POSIX docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01_01) which says the character classes depend on locale:

```
punct    <exclamation-mark>;<quotation-mark>;<number-sign>;\
         <dollar-sign>;<percent-sign>;<ampersand>;<apostrophe>;\
         <left-parenthesis>;<right-parenthesis>;<asterisk>;\
         <plus-sign>;<comma>;<hyphen>;<period>;<slash>;\
         <colon>;<semicolon>;<less-than-sign>;<equals-sign>;\
         <greater-than-sign>;<question-mark>;<commercial-at>;\
         <left-square-bracket>;<backslash>;<right-square-bracket>;\
         <circumflex>;<underscore>;<grave-accent>;<left-curly-bracket>;\
         <vertical-line>;<right-curly-bracket>;<tilde>
```

```bash
$ echo 'abcd_!"#$%()*+,-./:;<=>?@][\\^`{}|~'"'" | tr -d '!"#$%()*+,-./:;<=>?@][\\^`{}|~'"'"
abcd_
```

The set of characters in the `tr` command should be straightforward except for backslash, `\\`, which has been escaped for `tr`, and single quote, `"'"`, which is being concatenated as a string quoted in double quotes, since you can't escape a single quote within single quotes.

I do prefer using [@jared_marmot's complement solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67797319/7381355), if possible, though. It is much neater.